# How to use Javascript to obtain information from this table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm using Tampermonkey to work on a script to automate some things.

I'm trying to obtain the Level of certain characters so that I can choose the lowest level and then click it to select it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<td class="box-select boxPk pad-10">
<label for="(NULL)">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" name="replacement" id="(NULL)" value="(NULL)">
<b><a href="#" onclick="pokedexTab('pid=(NULL)', 1); return false;">Robert</a></b> <i class="ion-female female"></i><br>
<img src="(image url)"><br>
<b class="color-maroon">Level:</b> 16<br>
<b class="color-maroon">Exp:</b> 8,000
</label>
</td>
```

I'm trying to obtain the Level of certain characters so that I can choose the lowest level and then click it to select it.

This whole td tag is clickable and has many like it in table, with different attributes for each.

Ignore (NULL)s, I just replaced that to unique IDs.

Thank you very much for reading this question and for any possible help you may offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  - assuming there is only one `Level:` in the cell

```js
let levels = [];
const $levelCells=$(".boxPk>label");
$levelCells.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("a").text()); // if you want the name you need to save it
  levels.push(parseInt($(this).text().split("Level: ")[1]));
})
const maxNum = Math.max(...levels) // 16
const minNum = Math.min(...levels) // 14
console.log("Min",minNum);
console.log("Max",maxNum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="box-select boxPk pad-10">
      <label for="(NULL)">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" name="replacement" id="(NULL)" value="(NULL)">
<b><a href="#" onclick="pokedexTab('pid=(NULL)', 1); return false;">Robert</a></b> <i class="ion-female female"></i><br>
<img src="(image url)"><br>
<b class="color-maroon">Level:</b> 14<br>
<b class="color-maroon">Exp:</b> 8,000
</label>
    </td>
    <td class="box-select boxPk pad-10">
      <label for="(NULL)">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" name="replacement" id="(NULL)" value="(NULL)">
<b><a href="#" onclick="pokedexTab('pid=(NULL)', 1); return false;">Frank</a></b> <i class="ion-female female"></i><br>
<img src="(image url)"><br>
<b class="color-maroon">Level:</b> 15<br>
<b class="color-maroon">Exp:</b> 8,000
</label>
    </td>
    <td class="box-select boxPk pad-10">
      <label for="(NULL)">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" name="replacement" id="(NULL)" value="(NULL)">
<b><a href="#" onclick="pokedexTab('pid=(NULL)', 1); return false;">Fred</a></b> <i class="ion-female female"></i><br>
<img src="(image url)"><br>
<b class="color-maroon">Level:</b> 16<br>
<b class="color-maroon">Exp:</b> 8,000
</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Almost. I wanted to give the matching name too but it is more code to save the name that goes with the numbers

Comment: That's fine, the name doesn't matter for this. The values you got are perfect.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having an issue.. I'm trying to use javascript to click the lowest level named Robert, but it doesn't seem to be working properly

Comment: `$levelCells.eq(levels.indexOf(minNum)).find(“a”).click()`